# Checkstyle differs from normal Java on naming convention for final variables?

Tags: java, variables, naming-conventions, final, checkstyle

For a private final variable, Checkstyle is recommending a name that matches '^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'. Shouldn't final variables be all caps?

e.g. Checkstyle wants test, tEST, or testTest.
Isn't the convention usually TEST?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the `public static final` variables - those that act as constants.

Comment: For all `static final` variables, not only `public`.

Comment: Source: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367

Comment: +1 `final`by itself does not mean constant (as it would in other programming languages). Only `static final` fields are constants, and those should be all caps. You generally want to define fields and variables as `final` if possible, but you wouldn't want them all caps.